# Using CASE in MySQL update statement to update different columns based on CASE condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update 2 columns from database based on some condition. I have `bid_limit` column which i need to update to `bid_limit-1`   when `bid_limit>0` otherwise i need to update `addon_limit` column to `addon_limit-1`.

I have tried following query but it didn't worked for me.

```
update tbl_user set (case when (bid_limit>0) then (bid_limit=bid_limit-1) else (addon_limit=addon_limit-1) end) where id='157'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` statement using `CASE WHEN` on the columns:

```
UPDATE tbl_user 
  SET addon_limit = CASE WHEN bid_limit <= 0 THEN addon_limit - 1 ELSE addon_limit END,
      bid_limit = CASE WHEN bid_limit > 0 THEN bid_limit - 1 ELSE bid_limit END
WHERE id = '157'
```

Make sure you set the `addon_limit` before the `bid_limit`:

> Single-table `UPDATE` assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.
>
> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.
> ***source:*** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is wrong choice for this situation. Because it stands for defining multiple conditions. When you have just 1 condition you should use `IF`. This way:

```sql
UPDATE tbl_user
SET
  addon_limit = IF(bid_limit > 0, addon_limit, addon_limit - 1),
  bid_limit = IF(bid_limit > 0, bid_limit - 1, bid_limit)
```